# More score for consecutive word match in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have only one field named 'description'. My search query is like this for description field `"bad pizza good burger"`.

I have these document:

```
1) pizza taste bad but American burger are good
2) good burger can be found in America
3) what is pizza good burger?
```

I want query to return result whichever has higher phrase match.
So from the above example. Result will be
3>2>1

In document 3 'pizza good burger' has 3 consecutive string match so this appears first.
In document 2 'good burger' 2 consecutive match so this will be second
Rest of the document will be matched based on default elastisearch similarity module.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

This query will help you out.

```
{
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "name": "bad pizza good burger"
   }
 } 
}
```

Comment: I think the above query will bring document 1 to be top. Since it matches all the keywords. I want document 3 to be top since it contains phrase 'good burger'

Comment: Have you checked its bring document 3 to  top

Comment: Are you using any analyzers over the fileds